# Batch File to Extract values when variable names change in each file

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, extract

OK, I have hundred of files that have a text header in them that includes one or more entries for a set of eight different variables (name, host, year, month, hour, minute, second). The first time the value is displayed it looks like:

```
@name 4 10
3 4 DHARLAN
```

Every time after this (and the variable sets can appear 1 to 100 times per file) it shows up only as:

```
3 4 DHARLAN
```

The problem comes in that what happens to be a 4 in this case can be any value between 1 & 99. So in the next file it might be:

```
3 15 DHARLAN
```

So really the of eavh variables entries are something like:

```
3 ## <value>
```

Where ## is determined earlier in the header by:

```
@name ## X
```

I don't understand enoyugh about how FOR /F TOKENS works to get anything that comes close.

```
What I need is to parse a directory and end up with a file something like:
<filenameA> <name1> <host1> <year1> <month1> <day1> <hour1> <minute1> <second1>
<filenameA> <name2> <host2> <year2> <month2> <day2> <hour2> <minute2> <second2>
<filenameB> <name1> <host1> <year1> <month1> <day1> <hour1> <minute1> <second1>
...
```

What I have so far:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('dir /a-d /s /b') DO call :findfile "%%i"

:findfile
REM Print Filename
FINDSTR /B /M "#UGC">>output.txt
REM set Name Variable, need 2nd word (7th & if exists (8th) character) from this line only
FINDSTR /B "@name">%%n
REM Find all lines with name variable
FINDSTR /B "3 %n%">>output.txt
```

Help is greatly appreciated, even suggestions to a program that can do this.

Comment: I think it would help for us to know what the values in your headers mean.  How do the headers represent name, host, year, month, day, hour, minute, and second?  Is @name the name or is DHARLAN the name?

Comment: Yes, they are variables for username, year, month, day, etc

Answer (score 0):

### Thoughts

So...This is how I read your question.  You have many files with many values and for each file you want output a single line of all the file's variables.  Each variable is composed of two lines.  1. The variable declaration (name) and 2. The variable value (DHARLAN).  These lines are associated by a number (1 to 99).  Is this correct?

This should get you started...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

<nul set /p "=">output.txt
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /a:-d /b /s') do if exist "%%~fF" (
    set "name="
    set "namenum="
    set "host="
    set "hostnum="
    set "year="
    set "yearnum="
    set "month="
    set "day="
    set "daynum="
    set "monthnum="
    set "hour="
    set "hournum="
    set "minute="
    set "minutenum="
    set "second="
    set "secondnum="
    set "count=0"
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%%~fF") do (
        for /f "tokens=1,2,3*" %%X in ("%%L") do (
            if "%%Y"=="!namenum!" set "name=%%Z" & set /a "count+=1"
            if "%%Y"=="!hostnum!" set "host=%%Z" & set /a "count+=2"
            if "%%Y"=="!yearnum!" set "year=%%Z" & set /a "count+=4"
            if "%%Y"=="!monthnum!" set "month=%%Z" & set /a "count+=8"
            if "%%Y"=="!daynum!" set "day=%%Z" & set /a "count+=16"
            if "%%Y"=="!hournum!" set "hour=%%Z" & set /a "count+=32"
            if "%%Y"=="!minutenum!" set "minute=%%Z" & set /a "count+=64"
            if "%%Y"=="!secondnum!" set "second=%%Z" & set /a "count+=128"
            if /i "%%X"=="@name" set "namenum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@host" set "hostnum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@year" set "yearnum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@month" set "monthnum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@day" set "daynum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@hour" set "hournum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@minute" set "minutenum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@second" set "secondnum=%%Y"
            if "!count!" equ "255" (
                echo %%~nxF !name! !host! !year! !month! !day! !hour! !minute! !second!>>output.txt
                set "name="
                set "namenum="
                set "host="
                set "hostnum="
                set "year="
                set "yearnum="
                set "month="
                set "day="
                set "daynum="
                set "monthnum="
                set "hour="
                set "hournum="
                set "minute="
                set "minutenum="
                set "second="
                set "secondnum="
                set "count=0"
            )
        )
    )
)

goto :eof

:End
endlocal
```

---

### Update

Here is an updated version of the script above with comments.  It should also address your comment below with the setup section and the `cd` command.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Setup
set "ResultsFolder=results"
set "ExportFile=output.txt"

:: Set the Working Directory
cd data

:: Verify that the Results folder exists
if not exist "%ResultsFolder%\*" md "%ResultsFolder%"
set "OutputFile=%ResultsFolder%\%ExportFile%"

:: Empty the results file.
<nul set /p "=">%OutputFile%

:: Loop through the files /a:-d in the directory and its subdirectories /s.
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /a:-d /b /s') do if exist "%%~fF" (
    call :Reset
    rem Loop through the file contents and parse each line.
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%%~fF") do (
        for /f "tokens=1,2,3*" %%X in ("%%L") do (
            rem Keep track of the variables.
            if "%%Y"=="!namenum!"   set "name=%%Z"   & set /a "count+=1"
            if "%%Y"=="!hostnum!"   set "host=%%Z"   & set /a "count+=2"
            if "%%Y"=="!yearnum!"   set "year=%%Z"   & set /a "count+=4"
            if "%%Y"=="!monthnum!"  set "month=%%Z"  & set /a "count+=8"
            if "%%Y"=="!daynum!"    set "day=%%Z"    & set /a "count+=16"
            if "%%Y"=="!hournum!"   set "hour=%%Z"   & set /a "count+=32"
            if "%%Y"=="!minutenum!" set "minute=%%Z" & set /a "count+=64"
            if "%%Y"=="!secondnum!" set "second=%%Z" & set /a "count+=128"
            if /i "%%X"=="@name"   set "namenum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@host"   set "hostnum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@year"   set "yearnum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@month"  set "monthnum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@day"    set "daynum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@hour"   set "hournum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@minute" set "minutenum=%%Y"
            if /i "%%X"=="@second" set "secondnum=%%Y"
            rem When a full set is reached print it out.
            if "!count!" equ "255" (
                echo %%~nxF !name! !host! !year! !month! !day! !hour! !minute! !second!>>%OutputFile%
                call :Reset
            )
            if "!count!" gtr "255" (
                echo %%~nxF: Incomplete Set Encountered.  Stopping parsing of this file, continuing to the next.
                rem You can also use other validations to identify incomplete sets.
            )
        )
    )
)

goto :eof

:: Reset all of the variables for the next set.
:Reset
set "name="
set "namenum="
set "host="
set "hostnum="
set "year="
set "yearnum="
set "day="
set "daynum="
set "month="
set "monthnum="
set "hour="
set "hournum="
set "minute="
set "minutenum="
set "second="
set "secondnum="
set "count=0"
goto :eof

:End
endlocal
```

#### Summary

This is a summary of what the script is doing and how it works.

1. The Main for loop, will loop through all files located within the current working directory. `dir /a:-d /b /s`
2. Inside this loop, we first setup the variables needed to keep track of the file variables. `:Reset`
3. The next for loop will open the file and read each line of the file. `%%L`
4. The third for loop will then parse the line for the relevant variable information. Retrieve the first, second, and all remaining tokens from the line (`1,2,*`) into variables (%%X, %%Y, %%Z)
5. Now perform logic to keep track of the variables sets.  If the variable number has been set and this line matches the variable number, then save the variable value.  Else if the variable name matches, retrieve the variable number for comparison on the following lines.
6. Also increment the set count number and when a full set has been discovered, write it to the output file with the filename.
7. Reset the variables for use with the next set.
8. If the count does not equal 255, the file is incorrectly formatted or has an incomplete set of variables.

#### Notes

This script is just what seems to be the best solution for the questions presented and the information provided therein.  I have had to make assumptions about the files being processed and therefore may requires some modifications.  If you want to show us a full examples of the file to be parsed, it would help in determining what to do.

Comment: This has been a great help, thanks. Not quite there yet: 
1) Would like to get it to read the files from a different directory. have changed the first "for" line to: 'code' for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir .\data /a:-d /b') do if exist "%%~fF" ( 
But that doesn't work.
2) The Echo redirect doesn't work. Only echos the active file, and none of the variables. echo to the screen works, just not the redirect to a file. The current line is: 'code'echo %%~nF !name! !host! !year! !month! !day! !hour! !minute! !second!>>%RESULTSFOLDER%\%EXPORTFILE%
3) Only grabbing the first set variables

Comment: Could you elaborate on how number 1 does not work.  Does the script crash or it fail to find the folder?  Also what are the values of `%RESULTSFOLDER%\%EXPORTFILE%`?  Note that `%RESULTSFOLDER%` must exist in order to create the output file.

Comment: David, thanks for the help, sorry I haven't been able to work on this for awhile. I'm back on it and will get back with answers shortly, but not sure what you meant by "number 1". TIA

Comment: @Locker  Sounds good and "Number 1" was in reference to your "1)" point in your comment above.

Comment: ok, I moved the ::Set Working Directory above the ::Verify as I was getting errors. The results folder and the output file are getting created, but the output file is empty and the cmd window runs the inner most loop twice and then goes to the reset and ends with `goto :eof` _The sytem cannot find the file E:\Testing\data\results._ and I can't find where/how it is trying to reference the results file

Comment: @Locker  Try it again, I just noticed that I had `/a:d` and not `a:-d`.  This was listing only directories and no files.  One little character can change the entire script.  **`:P`**

Comment: The error immediately above was caused by the `dir /a:d /b /s` as that was listing the sub-directories and then the next for loop was trying to open the directory as if it were a file. For now I've turned off the `/s` as I can live without recursive and changed to `/a:-d` so I do not get any directories returned. but now my output file only contains a random(?) number of file name entries (minus the file extension (huh?). Not what I need. I'm not sure how this will work without a findstr use since the number variables (i.e. NameNum) are determined by the word following a known string.

Comment: I've got to remember to refresh this page before posting *G* So, I'm not sure why the output file has repeats of the directory listings and I'm not getting any other variable sent to the output.  Still working on it...

Comment: @Locker  It is only outputting the filename (without extension) because that is what I specified when I assumed that is what you wanted for `<filenameA>`...  I have updated my answer to now output the full filename with extension.  For all the file output options see the `for` command help text. `for /?`.